# custom html module with background transparent in joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, module

I would like to have a custom html module in my Joomla website. This custom html module need to be with a transparent background, so I've added in style the following:

```
#newsletter{
      background: none !important;
}
```

But it does not work.

There is a div above the one used for my custom html module that has a white background, but I need to have transparent bg only where I use my custom module. Infact, if I override the css of the parent div, it affects all divs around the website with same class...

```
<div class="module">
   <div class="mycustommodule">
   </div>
</div>

.module_menu, div.module {
background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
margin: 0 0 30px;
position: relative;
}
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: post the custom module css

Comment: the only css I use is the one I've posted

Comment: may be parent CSS overlapping..

Comment: Are you calling the right div? If you inspect the module with firebug, did you find the one with the background color. There could be another div within which also has a background color set within.

Comment: There is a div above the custom html module that has white background...how can I override it?

Comment: have you tried `opacity:0;` ?

Comment: I need to remove the white background only where I use my custom html...is there a way to do it with css? I edit my question.

Comment: so you want `div.module` background color from `white` to `transparent`

Comment: you can use `hsl` `background: hsl(40, 60%, 90%);` here is just a demo. http://jsbin.com/vibuwufive/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: You're not putting the css in the module layout are you?   Are you adding a module class to the specific module that you want to modify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgba` like this:

```
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `newsletter` (note the space) as the module class suffix in the advanced tab when editing the module in the module manager.

Add

```
.newsletter{
      background: none !important;
}
```

To the appropriate file in your template less folder or css folder if you are not using less. (Do this in the template manager)
Compile the less. (click the compile button in the template manager)